# How do I breed a Gold dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I recently received an update message introducing a new **Gold Dragon** in DragonVale.

How do I breed a Gold dragon, and how will I know if I got one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [DragonVale Wikia](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Dragon):

> To breed a Gold Dragon, it has been established that the elements metal and fire must be present. This means many combinations are possible. The Gold Dragon can be bred at either the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

It goes on to say that the breeding time is 48 hours, or 38 hours and 24 minutes in an upgraded Breeding Cave/Island.

You must, however, be at least Level 17 before you are able to breed the Gold dragon.

<sup>Note: Level 17 is *your* required level, not the required level of your dragons.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Allegedly chrome and scorch, like ruby. But everytime I keep getting firework so just try a lot

Answer (score 0):

I got a 48 hour incubation on chrome and scorch so that would be a possible way to go!

Answer (score 0):

It is forge and crystal. I got it first try.

It is very easy to get a rainbow with the scorch and chrome too. Also the fireworks is also very common to get. I have gotten two rainbow and I lost count on how many fireworks I got.